# PHP preg_match for grabbing YouTube ID from img.youtube.com too

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I have implemented a function for grabbing Youtube ID and i use the regular expression:

```
preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=|[^/]+/.+/)|youtu\.‌​be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $sourceCode, $youtube))
```

My problem is that this resular expression doesn't grab the id from a URL like: http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mW35zprs/0.jpg

So, how can i change it to work as it works right now but by giving me the "Di9mQ35zprs" from a URL "http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mW35zprs/0.jpg" too?

- THERE ARE MANY OTHER QUESTIONS REGARDING GRABBING YOUTUBE ID WITH PREG_MATCH, BUT NOONE OF THEM ANSWERS HOW TO GRAB FROM A URL http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mW35zprs/0.jpg TOO.

All i want to achieve is to replace my current preg_match and enable it to grab youtube ID from http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mW35zprs/0.jpg urls.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) first. Now your regexp looks like it came straight from hell.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
 $videoId = preg_replace("/.*v[=i]\/?(\w+).*/", '\1', "http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg");
```

The function will return the id you want. It should work with both types of URL you described.

Comment: It seems to be working fine:  `$videoId = preg_replace("/.*v[=i]\/?(\w+).*/", '\1', "http://img.youtube.com/vi/Di9mQ35zprs/0.jpg");  echo $videoId; //outputs Di9mQ35zprs`   and `$videoId = preg_replace("/.*v[=i]\/?(\w+).*/", '\1', "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhxXvEzVXXM");  echo $videoId; //outputs bhxXvEzVXXM`